# Calling a future in a stream with firebase auth and firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to have a StreamProvider provide a 'kaizenUser' object throughout the rest of the app. To get this 'KaizenUser' i've pulled the user from firebase authentication. Then using the uid of the firebase auth user, ive used that to access my own user doc form firebase.firestore to create the KaizenUser with the added 'role' information from my firestore user.

Spent a few days wrestling with the code in auth service and i think i'm so close...

Starting with the StreamProvider:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<KaizenUser>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Auth Service class.
The get user stream calls userFromFirebaseUser, in which I call getRole to find the document reference of the equivalent user in firestore and the 'role' field.
Then back in userFromFirebaseUser, use that role field to create a complete KaizenUser which will be passed through the stream.

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<KaizenUser> get user async* {
    yield* _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
  }

  //Create KaizenUser object based on firebase user
  KaizenUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    String role = getRole(user.uid) as String;
    KaizenUser kaizenUser =
        KaizenUser(uid: user.uid, email: user.email, role: role);
    return kaizenUser;
  }

  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<String> getRole(String uid) async {
    var doc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
    return doc.data()['role'];
  }
```

The error is:
Type Future is not of type String in type cast.

Whilst writing this out im thinking the problem line of code the cast 'as String'

```
String role = getRole(user.uid) as String;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are not awaiting for the future result to be returned. Try the following :

```
String role = await getRole(user.uid):
```

Comment: Correct, I was using my smartphone and could not completely see your code when I answered your question or I would have suggested you the changes you made. Did it solve your problem though?

Comment: that change sends me down a path of changes with and at the end im even more confused: 

I tried that, then had to add async to  _userFromFirebaseUser function and change the return to Future<KaizenUser>.

Then i have to change the Stream to Stream<Future<KaizenUser>>.

Then in the StreamProvider change it to <Future<kaizenUser>>

Comment: and lastly in all the provider endpoints in the widget tree change them all to future kaizen users but then in the tree at one of the end points:
```
final user = Provider.of<Future<KaizenUser>>(context);
```
i usually call user.uid on that Provider.of but uid isn't available for it anymore because its now a future. the options now are: asStream(), catchError(), then(), whenCompleted(), timeout().

Comment: If you had so many other changes to make, you could have simply tried >>>  String role = Future.value(getRole(user.uid));

Comment: Boom thats what i was after! I knew when i started going down that line that there must be a way to keep the change just in the auth service class

Comment: Damn, that sets me down another path. 
I do that and it doesn't want to save as a normal string it wants to be a Future<String>. So then in the line below (in _userFromFirebaseUser) when i initiate the KaizenUser it doesn't want to accept the Future<KaizenUser> variable.
One day i'll wrap my head around futures, but everytime i get involved with them it just ends up making long paths of changes that mess everything up